# How to set value when multiple java bean class is there

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm having three model class MyApp, Product and ProductDetails. I'm trying to set value in ProductDetails but I'm getting null pointer exception. Can someone please help me what I'm doing wrong here:

**MyApp.java**

```
public class MyApp {

    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {

    private ProductDetails details;

    public ProductDetails getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(ProductDetails details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

}
```

**ProductDetails.java**

```
public class ProductDetails {

    private String productName;

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {

        this.productName = productName;
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp m = new MyApp();
        m.getProduct().getDetails().setProductName("testProduct");
        System.out.println("Name : " + m.getProduct().getDetails().getProductName());

    }

}
```

I'm getting below exception:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptio at Test.main(Test.java:7)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize product.details and details.productName before using it. For example:

```
m.getProduct().setDetails(new ProductDetails());
m.getProduct().getDetails().setProductName(...);
```

What about the Product in Variable m?

Comment: This is correct. Although there, for this use case, it might be more useful to create the instances in the constructors.

Comment: Yes, there is more than one way to do it. This was just one example how the problem can be solved.